Laravel Tailwind styles not loading on XAMPP with Apache on Windows 10 - How to fix ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT?
I’m new to Laravel and I want to run the project using Apache from XAMPP on Windows 10.
What I did was copy the project to xampp/htdocs/, run npm run build, and modify the .env file, as well as httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd.conf.
However, when I access the app, it loads everything—the login page, the database—but something is not loading: the Tailwind styles. In the console, I get the error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT for the following resources:
http://[::1]:5173/resources/css/app.css
http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client
http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.js.

After exploring the web, I found one of the many solutions that suggests deleting the public/hot file, which contains http://[::1]:5173. After deleting it, everything works fine.
Is there a more elegant solution for this?
